# Phonegap iOS: Download image to Photo Library

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is it possible to download a file (image) and save it in the Photo Library?

I am aware of this [download](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer_download) method, but it only allows to download to a location that I specify.

On iOS I was unable to get the path to the Photo Library (and I know it doesn't just store it there, but also adds it to a DB)

Does phonegap provide this ability in some way?
Do I need to write a dedicated plugin for this?

Thanks,
Nadav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ehh... I hate answering my own questions

I found this was impossible without a Phonegap plugin, and couldn't find one that does that,
so I wrote one.
Currently only iOS and Android are supported.
https://github.com/grnadav/SaveToPhotoAlbumPhonegapPlugin

Feel free to expand it's functionality and pull-request :)