# Cordova/Phonegap store image in photo library

Tags: cordova

I am using the latest version of Cordova and I want to store an image into the photo library of iOS. How do I do that?

Comment: Photo from online? Use file transfer plugin

Comment: Look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982028/phonegap-ios-download-image-to-photo-library

Comment: Its a local image created by the app